# What is ‘intelligent’ complementing in the beginning of this sentence?

Tags: infinitives, complements, infinitive-phrases

I have the following sentence and diagram:

> To sound intelligent on political issues was Wayne’s goal.
> [image]

The infinitive phrase is the subject of the sentence. What is *intelligent* complementing exactly, *sound*? Is it a [subjective complement](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/273967/104666) since *sound* is intransitive?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so we are dealing here with:

> An infinitive clause¹ (also called a nonfinite² infinitival clause)
> allows us to repackage information, more than a noun phrase can
> contain, and **place it in the subject or object position of a clause**.
> **In the subject position, an infinitive clause is usually followed by
> some form of be or a static verb.** It is uncommon to begin a clause
> with an infinitive clause, with a few exceptions such as dictionary
> definitions, quotes and poetic speech.
>
> Infinitive phrase vs. infinitive clause — An infinitive structure, in
> traditional grammar, is called an infinitive phrase because it can not
> stand alone as a sentence (i.e., it does not have a subject and
> predicate). In contrast, **in linguistic description,** it is called an
> **infinitival nonfinite clause because it typically does not have a
> subject and its verb form is not inflected for person, number or
> tense**; also, the term "phrase" is reserved for word groups such as
> noun phrase, verb phrase, adjective phrase, verb phrase, etc.

So: *To sound intelligent on political issues* **was** *Wayne's goal*.

Why start the sentence with the infinitive? **For emphasis.**

That said: |to sound intelligent| is the subject.
The predicate is |was|.
And |Wayne's goal| is the subject complement (not object, *as a be verb does not take objects*).

Bear in mind that usually a sentence would be structured like this:
*Wayne's goal was to sound intelligent on political issues*.
In that case, |Wayne's goal| is the subject of the sentence, the predicate is |was| and |to sound intelligent| is the subject complement.

[grammar quizzes, great explanation](https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/infinitive1.html)

Answer (score 0):

*To sound intelligent on political issues* is an infinitive phrase that functions as a noun and the subject in the sentence. The verb *sound* is a linking verb in the infinitive phrase, that is why the adjective *intelligent* is not a complement of this verb. So, there is no overt subject for the infinitive phrase in the sentence and the adjective *intelligent* can't be an overt complement of anything in the sentence.
But, if we rearrange the sentence in *for counstruction*, *It is a goal for Wayne to sound intelligent on political issues* , it is possible to understand that the adjective *intelligent* is a so called *implied complement* of the noun *Wayne* in the possessive in the infinitive phrase *to sound intelligent on political issues* in the sentence. Or, the adjective *intelligent* is a complement by implication of the word *Wayne*.